# not able to install Liferay with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, installation, liferay, liferay-ide

I am trying to get started with Liferay with eclipse. So while installing the plugin I am getting error saying 'Can not complete because one or more required items can not be found' [image]

[image]

[image]

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Liferay IDE 3.1.0.201705141336-b1 (com.liferay.ide.eclipse.tools.feature.group 3.1.0.201705141336-b1)
>     Missing requirement: biz.aQute.remote.api 3.4.0.201705121927-SNAPSHOT (biz.aQute.remote.api 3.4.0.201705121927-SNAPSHOT) requires 'package org.osgi.framework.dto [1.8.0,2.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Blade Tools 2.1.0.REL-20170514-003119-g924bba6 (com.liferay.blade.tools.feature.group 2.1.0.REL-20170514-003119-g924bba6)
>       To: biz.aQute.remote.api [3.4.0.201705121927-SNAPSHOT]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Liferay IDE 3.1.0.201705141336-b1 (com.liferay.ide.eclipse.tools.feature.group 3.1.0.201705141336-b1)
>       To: com.liferay.blade.tools.feature.group 2.0.0

Comment: You need to show us the complete 'Details' from that last image because the vital information has been cut off.

Comment: hey greg, updated now

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: using eclipse indigo

Answer (score 1):

Your version of Eclipse is far too old for this code.

The error is saying that it needs at least version 1.8 of the `org.osgi.framework.dto` package. This package was not added to Eclipse until Eclipse 4.4. The current version of Eclipse (Eclipse Neon.3) contains version 1.8 of this package.